# Regression model BY categories using tapply() in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to use `tapply()` function to run models by several categories with not much sucess. My data has 20 clinics and I want to run the models BY each clinic.

Heres my model:

```
attach(qregdata)
rq(logA~ dose+ chtcm + cage +raceth + sex,tau=.9)
```

My data as a variable clinic (with values 1-20). Does anybody know how to run this model BY clinic in R as in other statistical packages?

Answer (score 0):

A very general way of accomplishing this is shown in the following. The `ddply` function runs a supplied function (in this case `lm`) for each `clinic`. You can also run it on more complex cross-sections of your data. E.g. `.(clinic,level)` would run a separate model on each combination of `clinic` and `level`. The term `lm(y~x)$coef[1]` gets the intercept of the linear model. I think there is no easy way to save all the output of each model fit at once.

```
n <- 10
clinic <- factor(rep(1:3,each=n))
x <- rep(0:(n-1),3)
y <- rnorm(3*n)*x
d <- data.frame(clinic,x,y)

# plot data and linear fits
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~clinic) + stat_smooth(method='lm')

# run a separate model for each clinic
library(plyr)
ddply(d,.(clinic),summarize,intercept=lm(y~x)$coef[1],slope=lm(y~x)$coef[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'lappy' across the unique values of clinic, and the use subset to extract the section of your Dataset for that clinic.  Then just fit the model to the subset.

This will return a list of models, which you can then further process.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this recently and wanted to share a response in case someone is still interested in this topic; sorry to dredge up an old post.

`tapply` is very convenient to work with when the input object (the object being "split") is a vector. If the input object being split is a rectangular data set, it can be much simpler to use the (aptly named, in this case) `by` function, which is a convenient wrapper for `tapply` intended for `data.frame` objects. The return object of the `by` function is of the class `by` which can be simplified to an `array` or a `list` using the argument `simplify = TRUE`.

Certainly there are more efficient ways to perform this operation, but if you are looking for a `tapply`-like solution - `by` is it.

Here's an example using `lm` to regress petal width on sepal width "`by`" species in the `iris` data set:

```
## Load iris data 
data(iris)

## Fit a model to each species-specific subset of the data 
fitBySpecies <- by(
    data    = iris,
    INDICES = iris$Species,
    FUN     = function(speciesSubset)
        lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width, data = speciesSubset)
)
```